# Raw body payload in AWS API Gateway Body Mapping Template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

For some reason I'm having a hard time getting the raw body from within the `event`. It's logging the `$input.body` as json for a `application/json` content-type. [The docs say that that should contain the raw payload.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference)

Here my Integration Request Body Mapping Template:

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "rawBody": $input.body,
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```

Here's the payload example:

```
{
  "event": {
    "body": {
      "hello": "meow"
    },
    "rawBody": {
      "hello": "meow"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Host": "7nuy7lymef.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Origin": "file://",
      "Postman-Token": "0ce7c6f4-3864-c9b4-f2db-739737b2ba49",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Postman/4.2.2 Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Electron/0.36.2 Safari/537.36",
      "Via": "1.1 1eea0bca59557555878da4d9775c509f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "SDjaGcuJ5eVkOMMCn6M3vGaVicA1fuA7h0bUYE4ARlKupO60eeYNFA==",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "206.71.230.14, 205.251.250.135",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "x_example_header": "my awesome header"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "params": {},
    "query": {
      "example_param": "myawesomeparam"
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": false,
    "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/reggi-log-post",
    "logStreamName": "2016/06/08/[$LATEST]aad04e0e46614c288ac8ca43d0a95076",
    "functionName": "reggi-log-post",
    "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
    "functionVersion": "$LATEST",
    "invokeid": "6e4e1e13-2dc1-11e6-a1f7-4dad3a8eb122",
    "awsRequestId": "6e4e1e13-2dc1-11e6-a1f7-4dad3a8eb122",
    "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:562508364089:function:reggi-log-post"
  }
}
```

- Is there any way to access the raw body from this request?
- Is there any way to change the content-type to accept all types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following blog post explains in detail how to get around this problem. https://nicholasjackson.io/2016/12/13/using-graphql-with-aws-lambda/

It's written specifically in the context of GraphQL, but it will work for any content type. In short:

- Go to the Binary Support section. Enable binary support for your chosen media type and save.
- Return to the your method in Resources section and open Integration Request. Add/edit the body mapping template for your chosen content type and put the following:

  `"rawBody": "$util.escapeJavaScript($util.base64Decode($input.body))"`
- Save and redeploy the API.

Adding binary support encodes the request as a base64 string. The body mapping template decodes it.

Comment: Don't forget the single quote escaping, otherwise it will throw `400 Bad Request`: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=900916&#900916 . `$util.escapeJavaScript(data).replaceAll("\\'","'")`

Answer (score 4):

`$input.body` contains the raw payload. You need to put quotes around it like `"rawBody": "$input.body"`. Otherwise the body will be interpreted as part of the json document.

Comment: should be comment.

Comment: When I do $input.body, an empty JSON object is returned { }, do you know the reason for this?

Comment: @fuzzi input the body data with POST method